# Static files from collection (Jekyll)

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have this site structure:

```
mysite
  _artworks
    category1
    category2
    category3
```

In `_config.yml` file I have:

```
collections:
 artworks:
  output: true
```

All static files are moved to a folder `_site`, but I can not refer them through `{{ site.artworks.static_files }}` in `index.html`.
In fact, I try to display pictures in cycle like this:

```
{% for art in site.artworks.static_files %}
    <img src="{{ art.path }}">
    <br>
    {{ art.path }}
    <br>
    <br>
    <br> 
{% endfor %}
```

Why is it not working? And how to best organize a collection to store photos and display them **by category**, if this  is a project gallery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the collection generated pages you need to browse them directly:

```
{% for art in site.artworks %}
    <img src="{{ art.path }}">
    {{ art.path }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you have specified any image with a special tag and the image filename in a category of the collection, then you can access them inside the loop with:

Supposing you have in your collection front matter: `my_image: hello.jpg` and you have an image in the assets folder `/assets/hello.jpg`

```
{% for art in site.artworks %}
    <img src="assets/{{art.my_image}}">
{% endfor %}
```

If your collections will just contain images, I would rather prefer specifying them in Jekyll **data** files and then include them in posts.

Comment: Thanks for answer!